# Cannot set button frame correctly over imageview in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, imageview, frame

I'm setting a button over an imageview, but can't get the frame right. I don't understand why. Here's an image of the problem: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZrZs_eLfZaOov1cf6Hi0NA37MHLQmyf_j39g172lXXc/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

I tried using tap gestures; that didn't work. I tried setting the frame by referencing the bounds and frame of the imageview, and that didn't work either

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be you should read more about differences between `frame` and `bound` properties of UIView.
In your code you should use:

```
clearButton.frame = [self.imageView convertRect:self.imageView.bounds toView:self.view];
[self.view addSubview:clearButton];
```

or

```
clearButton.frame = self.imageView.bounds;
[self.imageView addSubview:clearButton];
self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

to set clearButton's frame and add it to a parent view.

Comment: Thank you for your slightly condescending and half correct response. Your second solution does not work because a button will not trigger when placed as a subview of an imageview. Your first solution produces a result that looks like the image at the top of the google document, which I have just updated now.

Comment: @djax Is imageView a subview of self? I have updated the first solution for case if it is not. I have also updated the second one.

Comment: I have updated the first solution to use convertRect:toView: method of UIView

Comment: clearButton.frame = [self.imageView convertRect:self.imageView.bounds toView:self.view]; doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: also in the line clearButton.frame = [self.imageView convertRect:self.imageView.bounds toView:self]; i get a warning for the "self", since shouldn't that be self.view?

Comment: @djax Sure, it should be self.view. And "[self.view addSubview:clearButton];"

Comment: Hmm the result was the same